# Simple Linq Query Not Working

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple function that filters a datatable based on the user's selected string values in combo boxes. If the checkboxes are checked, then the selected string in the combo box is match criteria for the where clause.

The problem I'm having is I'm only getting back one record, the first record, rather then a couple of hundred.

Sorry I'm new at Linq, what am I doing wrong?

```
private DataTable FilterDMRMarcIDs()
{
    var tmpValue = dtDMRMarc.AsEnumerable();

    if (chekbCountry.Checked)
    {
        tmpValue = tmpValue.Where(contact => contact.Field<string>("Country") == cbCountry.SelectedItem);
    }
    if (chekbState.Checked)
    {
        tmpValue = tmpValue.Where(contact => contact.Field<string>("State") == cbState.SelectedItem);
    }
    return tmpValue.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
}    // FilterDMRMarcIDs() ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, it's always the silly things you miss. It never hurts to over specify types!

```
private DataTable FilterDMRMarcIDs()
{
    var tmpValue = dtDMRMarc.AsEnumerable();

    if (chekbCountry.Checked)
    {
         tmpValue = tmpValue.Where(contact => contact.Field<string>("Country") == (string)cbCountry.SelectedItem);
    }
    if (chekbState.Checked)
    {
        tmpValue = tmpValue.Where(contact => contact.Field<string>("State") == (string)cbState.SelectedItem);
    }
    return tmpValue.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
}    // FilterDMRMarcIDs() ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution Eric Matson provided is kind of right. [ComboBox.SelectedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an `Object` and `contact.Field<T>` returns `T` so in your case it returns `String`.

I would recommend to do the following:

```
tmpValue.Where(contact => contact.Field<string>("State")
                        .Equals(Convert.ToString(cbState.SelectedItem)));
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to do selected value instead of selected item

Comment: I used a break point and verified that cbState.SelectedItem is a string of a state name.